# Query CosmosDb Unstructured JSON

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can CosmosDB Query the values of the properties within a dynamic JSON?

The app allows storing a JSON as a set of custom properties for an object. They are serialized and stored in CosmosDb. For example, here are two entries:

```
{
    "id": "ade9f2d6-fff6-4993-8473-a2af40f071f4",
    ...
    "Properties": {
        "fn": "Ernest",
        "ln": "Hemingway",
        "a_book": "The Old Man and the Sea"
    },
    ...
}
```

and

```
{
    "id": "23cb9d4c-da56-40ec-9fbe-7f5178a92a4f",
    ...
    "Properties": {
        "First Name": "Salvador",
        "Last Name": "Dali",
        "Period": "Surrealism"
    },
    ...
}
```

How can the query be structured so that it searches in the values of `Properties`?

Comment: Are you talking about C# LINQ query or SQL query?

Comment: Anything :) But I guess SQL would be best as more people could use the idea.

Comment: @Ovi Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong - it definitely did. I ended up modifying it a bit. Just posted as a comment to your answer

Comment: @Ovi Thanks for your modify.I already summarized it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m looking for something that doesn’t involve the name of the
>   sub-propety, like SELECT * FROM c WHERE
>   some_function_here(c.Properties, ‘Ernest’)

Maybe I get your idea that you want to filter the documents by the value of the `Properties`, not the name. If so , you could use [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf) in cosmos db.

***sample udf:***

```
function query(Properties,filedValue){
    for(var k in Properties){  
        if(Properties[k] == filedValue)
            return true;  
    }
    return false;
}
```

***sample query:***

```
SELECT  c.id FROM c where udf.query(c.Properties,'Ernest')
```

***output:***

[image]

---

Just summary here, Ovi's udf function like:

```
function QueryProperties (Properties, filedValue) {     
    for (var k in Properties) { 
        if (Properties[k] && Properties[k].toString().toUpperCase().includes(filedValue.toString().toUpperCase())) 
            return true;    
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up modifying it a bit, but the idea is perfect: `function QueryProperties (Properties, filedValue) {
    for (var k in Properties) {
        if (Properties[k] && Properties[k].toString().toUpperCase().includes(filedValue.toString().toUpperCase()))
            return true;          
    }
    return false;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following syntax's will work.

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.Properties["First Name"] = 'Salvador'

SELECT * FROM c where c.Properties.fn = 'Ernest'
```

Comment: That doesn’t quite solve the problem Nick. I’m looking for something that doesn’t involve the name of the sub-propety, like `SELECT * FROM c WHERE some_function_here(c.Properties, ‘Ernest’)`

Comment: @Ovi That wasn't clear in your question. Jay's UDF will solve the problem.