# Filter datetime value within a JSON collection of a collection inside CosmoDB using SQL

Tags: sql, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

Using Microsoft CosmoDBs SQL like syntax. I have a collection of entries that follow a schema like this (simplified for this post)

```
{"id":"123456",
 "activities": {
       "activityA": {
                "loginType": "siteA",
                "lastLogin": "2018-02-06T19:42:22.205Z"
            },
       "activityB": {
                "loginType": "siteB",
                "lastLogin": "2018-03-07T11:39:50.346Z"
            },
       "activityC": {
                "loginType": "siteC",
                "lastLogin": "2018-04-08T15:21:15.312Z"
            }
        }
}
```

Without knowing the exact index into the activities entry activities list/sub collection, how can I query to get back all items in the Cosmo db collection that have a "lastLogin" matching a date range?

If I only wanted to search on the first item in the activities list, I could do something like this using index 0.

```
SELECT * FROM c where (c.activities[0].lastLogin > '2018-01-01T00:00:00') and (c.activities[0].lastLogin <= '2019-02-15T00:00:00')
```

But I want to search all entries in the list. Would be nice if there was something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c where (c.activities[?].lastLogin > '2018-01-01T00:00:00') and (c.activities[?].lastLogin <= '2019-02-15T00:00:00')
```

But that doesn't exist.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481606/query-cosmosdb-unstructured-json

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can not iterate over a non list collection. Had the collection item been structured like this

```
{"id":"123456",
 "activities": [
            {   "label": "activityA",
                "loginType": "siteA",
                "lastLogin": "2018-02-06T19:42:22.205Z"
            },
            {
                "label": "activtyB",
                "loginType": "siteB",
                "lastLogin": "2018-03-07T11:39:50.346Z"
            }, 
etc...
```

It would be easy to crease a UDF to iterate over with something like this

**UDF: filterActivityList**

```
function(activityList,  targetDateTimeStart, targetDateTimeEnd) {
    var s, _i, _len;
    for (_i = 0, _len = activityList.length; _i < _len; _i++) {

        s = activityList[_i];

        if ((s.lastLogin >= targetDateTimeStart) && (s.lastLogin < targetDateTimeEnd)) 
        {

            return true;
       }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Then to query:

select * from c WHERE udf.filterActivityList(c.activities, '2018-01-01T00:00:00', '2018-02-01T00:00:00');

If I were to leave the structure as a JSON hierarchy instead of converting it to a JSON list then I would have to write another udf to accept the top level node of the hierarchy as an input parameter and have it convert the notes under it to a list, then apply the udf.filterActivityList UDF to the result. From my experience this approach is resource intensive and takes a very long time for Cosmo to process.